# The time to hatch between $k_1$ and $k_2$ eggs (if hatching times are independent and exponentially distributed)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have $N$ eggs that each hatch after a time given by independent exponentially distributed random variables with identical rate parameters $\lambda \space seconds^{-1}$.  At our initial time $t = 0$, none of the eggs have hatched.

As a function of the time $t$, what is the probability that (at a given time $t_i$) between $k_1$ and $k_2$ of the $N$ eggs have hatched (where $k_1 \leq k_2 \leq N$)?  For another example, if we wait five seconds, we might want to ask: what is the probability P(at least two eggs have hatched AND at most five eggs have hatched)?

Comment: Your question makes no sense and what have you done in class?

Comment: @Lost1 What about my question makes no sense?  I have some number of processes that occur at (originally unknown) times drawn from the same exponential distribution, and I want to know, as a function of time, the probability that a bounded number of them have occurred?

Comment: Between $N \geq k_1$ and $N\geq k_2$  are hatched?

Comment: @Lost1 Is this the confusing part?  It might be written poorly.  I just meant that between some integer number $k_1$ and $k_2$ of the $N$ eggs have hatched.  Here $k_1$ and $k_2$ are both integers $\leq N$ and $k_1 \leq k_2$.  For example, we could have $N = 10$ and $k_1 = 0$ and $k_2 = 5$.

Comment: Hmm interesting...

Comment: @Lost1 Please let me know if this question needs to be made clearer or is otherwise poorly defined, and I will do my best.

Comment: Ah the answer is a mixture of binomial and exponential.

Comment: @Lost1 I've been stuck trying to find an analytic expression for the probability.  Do you think one exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

There is no nice way to write the sum, sorry.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.